# This line sounds peculiar, I would appreciate your opinions (it uses the verb 許される)

Tags: translation, verbs, conjugations

First of all, to give you some context, there are 3 characters that will be referred to as A, B, and C. The following lines are from a dialogue between A and B about C. The character C has done things that are considered wrong, unforgivable actually, and that's why in the dialogue there is 許される.

Character A does not approve of what C did. However, B is grateful; he is on the side of C.

> B: むしろ俺は感謝してるっスよ。
>
> A: **許されることじゃねー**だろ。
>
> B: **許される**って誰に？つーか…なんでそんな無下にできんスか？

I'm fairly certain that A is saying something like "But, it's unforgivable." 
"That sort thing shouldn't be allowed." (referring to C's actions)
The subject are his actions, right? I say this because if A had wanted to say "I can't forgive/allow/him for what he does", I believe (あいつを）**許せない** would have worked or **許されない.**

Regarding B's line where he says 許されるって誰に？ if it sounds like he doesn't approve of what A said, and given that he also quotes what he said (with the use of って), personally I consider that it would have sounded better if B had also negated the verb, as in, to say: "Unforgivable, you say? By whom?"

Would have made sense in my opinion and much easier to translate, but it's not like that and I'm not sure what B is implying.

Answer (score 5):

> personally I consider that it would have sounded better if B had also negated the verb

If Person A had said 許されないことだろ, this is true. But って is a quoting particle, and what he actually said is 許される(ことじゃない), not 許されない.

Literally:

> A: 許されることじゃねーだろ。
>  It's not something that's to be forgiven.
>
> B: 許されるって誰に？
>  "Forgiven", by who?
>  <sub>(implies "Regarding this matter, no one allows or disallows anything.")</sub>

I think English speakers won't say "Unforgiven by who?" in this context, either.